# How can I get the full C# stack trace for an exception, like I see in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, debugging

In Visual Studio, when the debugger stops at an exception, the stack trace looks like this:

```
Program1.exe!Program1.MainForm.debug_throw_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 2799 + 0x2a bytes  C#
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x53 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0xb6 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) + 0x237 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mea) + 0xef bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mea) + 0x34 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks) + 0x48b bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xe49 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x8c bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x55 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x15a bytes  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x681 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x57c bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x6f bytes    
Program1.exe!Program1.Program.Main() Line 351 + 0x5 bytes   C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x5a bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x285 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x9 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x57 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x51 bytes   
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

but when I catch an unhandled Exception via System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException and print its StackTrace property then I only see

```
at Flip.MainForm.debug_throw_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\q4-trunk1\Flip\MainForm.cs:line 2799
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I don't care about that bottom section (VisualStudio.HostingProcess and below), but I do care about the bit between where Exception.StackTrace stops and that.  How can I get the full stack trace?  (I ask because sometimes I get stack traces from problems where some component is pumping the message loop, but I cannot see which component because the trace isn't going far enough.)

Comment: Stack traces through native code are unreliable without a separate debugger process (especially when handling an error where your program is already in a compromised state).  You can write a debugger of course, the API is documented.  But often what you really want is to get a stack trace from failures outside your debugging environment, and for that you should consider writing a minidump which can be brought back to Visual Studio and inspected.

Comment: @Ben: so you are saying that because the stack will always stop when it hits native code, even if there is managed code on the other side?

Comment: No, I'm saying that because it's true.  Specifically, walking the stack requires taking some global locks temporarily; if those locks are already in use then you will deadlock.  So stack trace through native code has to be done from another process, using the debug API, unless you can guarantee that none of those locks are taken.  During exception handling, you can't, so you need a separate process.  Either one you write, or a tool already made for the job.

Comment: Of course, there are other possible problems too.  If you are handling an OutOfMemory exception, you can easily trigger another one while building the error report.  Ditto for StackOverflowException.  But those caveats also apply to fully managed code.

Answer (score 1):

Environment.StackTrace seems to provide a fuller stack trace in some circumstances.

Comment: this returns a string not a stack trace object

Comment: @Shadowblitz16, the question didn't ask for a stack trace object.

Comment: your right my bad. stack overflow won't let me edit my downvote.